# Get the value of items in checkboxlist and save in hiddenfield

Tags: jquery

I have a checkboxlist.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">                                                 
<asp:ListItem Value="S04">1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="S08">2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="S09">3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and hidden field

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hddnValue" runat="server" />
```

I want to store the selected value of checkboxlist in HiddenField.

Generated HTML

```
<td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblList$0" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_0">1</label></td>

<td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblList$1" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_1">2</label></td>

<td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblList$2" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_2">3</label></td>

<td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cblList$3" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cblList_3">4</label></td>
```

I tried

```
    $(function() {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConfirm').click(function() {
        debugger;
        var val = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
            val[i] = $(this).val();
        });
    });
});
```

without any luck. Please Help.

Thank you,

Rahul

Comment: can you share the generated html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively You can do something like this

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConfirm').click(function () {
    var val = [];
    $('#cblList').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
        val.push($(this).val());
    })
    $('#hddnValue').val(val.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add a `class` on to the hidden field to make it easier to identify:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hddnValue" CssClass="selectedItems" runat="server" />
```

Then in your jQuery use `map()` to create an array of the selections and set the value to the comma separated listing:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnConfirm').click(function() {
    var values = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).join(',');
    $('.selectedItems').val(values);
});
```